# How do I reset the Simulator in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9

I'm trying to reset it. In Xcode 8 we went to "Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings". I don't see that in Xcode 9 and need to wipe my simulator.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I found it. It is now under "Hardware -> Erase All Content and Settings"

Edit: In Xcode 11 it is now under "Device -> Erase All Content and Settings"

Comment: I'm using Xcode 9.2 and I don't see a "Hardware" tab.

Comment: @Attila It's in the Simulator's menu tabs, not Xcode's.

Comment: Do I have to do this for each simulator instance or only once for all simulators?

Comment: You'll have to do it for each simulator.

Answer (score 8):

**Xcode 9.4**

You need to click on Simulator first. Hardware > Erase All Content and Settings.
This will reset the simulator. Wait for a minute for the Simulator to rebuild.

[image]

Comment: Do I have to do this for each simulator instance or only once for all simulators?

Answer (score 7):

**Xcode 11.4**

The simulator app no longer has the `Hardware` menu. It is now the `Device` menu.

Device > Erase All Content and Settings

[image: Erase All Content and Settings location]