# Can I delete .js files when writing code in NativeScript and Typescript

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I'm writing an app in NativeScript, using Typescript and Angular.

Something weird happened - suddenly the code I write in main.ts file has no effect on the app. I checked to see - the corresponding main.js file did npt change after running '`tns build ios/android`' and '`tns run ios/android`'.

So I want to ask - since when writing in NativeScript - every .ts file gets "translated" to .js file - is it safe to delete the corresponding main.js file so that a new updated main.js file is created?

Thanks.

Comment: Also, please try to answer why my .ts files became ineffective? Only code changed in .js files really changes the app. Thanks.

Comment: Hi  Mickelson Morely, if you delete the JavaScript file(in your case `main.js`), the file will be generated again when the TypeScript files are transpiled to JavaScript. Regarding the issue you are facing, it seems like a local problem with the TypeScript compiler. If you are having a similar issue again, try deleting `node_modules`, `hook` and `platforms` folders and build the project again via `tns run ios/android`

Comment: Yes I did that, but it didn't help. The solution I had to do was this - doing a "hard-reset" for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *Nikolay Tsonev* mentioned in his comment, there was a problem in transpiling TypeScript files to Javascript in this project, while in other projects - transpilling worked fine

So the way I solved this was to do a "hard-reset" like this:

1. Shutdown all terminal windows and threads.

   2. Deleting `node_modules`, `hook` and `platforms` folders.
   3. Reset xCode simulator by choosing "Hardware -> Erase All Content and Settings" (more on this here:
      [How do I reset the Simulator in Xcode 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46372976/how-do-i-reset-the-simulator-in-xcode-9))
   4. Close AVD emulator and wipe its data.
   5. Reset the mac (I was working on the same session without reset for almost two months).
   6. Install a fresh project from the beginning, using:

> ```
> tns create ns-audio11 --template tns-template-hello-world-ts
>
> cd ns-audio11
>
> tns platform add android
>
> tns platform add iOS
>
> tns run android
>
> tns run ios
>
> code .
> ```

And now Typescript code was effective again!